# CSS Files showing up with type text/plain

Tags: css, jekyll

I am attempting to serve my static blog (powered by jekyll) on my Ubuntu server but the CSS does not apply and I keep getting the issue:

```
"Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain".
```

In the source code, however, I explicitly list that these files are "text/css". Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: upload your piece of code.. <head> of the document

Answer (score 28):

This was an Nginx issue. I needed to place

```
include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
```

in the "location /" block.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set "rel='stylesheet' attribute.